# update_post_meta

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to update a custom field for a custom post type with this function
php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updatemeta', 'toggle_task_status');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updatemeta', 'toggle_task_status');
function toggle_task_status () {
    $post_id = $data['post_id'];
    return update_post_meta($post_id , 'task_status', 'open');
}
```

javascript

```
jQuery("form").on("submit", function () {
    console.log("hello");
    var post_id = jQuery("#post_id").val();
    console.log(post_id);
    var post_data = {
                    action: "updatemeta",
                    data: {
                        post_id: post_id,
                    }
                };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://cloud-accounting.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: post_data,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        error: function (jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("it is not working   "+textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log("it is working");
        }
    
    })
})
```

and the code gives me success but it doesn't work , I see the same before and after the request

Comment: Ypu're not passing $data to toggle_task_status() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're actually getting the post ID sent by the javascript.

```
function toggle_task_status () {
    $post_id = $_POST['data']['post_id'];
    $update = update_post_meta($post_id , 'task_status', 'open');
    if($update){
        wp_send_json('success');
    } else {
        wp_send_json('fail');
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

and then in your javascript

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response); // should be either 'success'  or 'fail'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , you saved me

Comment: You're very welcome :)